# Scroll controlled SVG animation got problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am trying to create a SVG illusration that animates when the user scrolls on the page (actually a simple path progression on a track & field graphic).

I tried to follow this cool code : https://codepen.io/chardy/pen/vEBvNP

But I get some strange result : when I scroll, the path doesn't get the same behavior as the example (strange progression of the path, like getting disappeared at its beginning, and the animation doesn't start and finish at the right points). I don't have much knowledges in SVG, and I think the problem is there but I don't know what...

Here's my code on codepen https://codepen.io/patrick38/pen/ZVbwRe or right here, thank you! :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset", "1000");
      $(".path").css("stroke-dasharray", "1000");

      var $dashOffset = $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset");

      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $percentageComplete =
            $(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height() - $(window).height()) * 100;

        var $newUnit = parseInt($dashOffset, 10);

        var $parsedPercentage = parseInt($percentageComplete, 10);

        var $offsetUnit = $percentageComplete * ($newUnit / 100);

        $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset", $newUnit - $offsetUnit); //.star
      });
    });
```

```css
.cls-1,
.cls-2 {
  fill: #b65534;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-5 {
  stroke: #fcfcfc;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-2,
.cls-3,
.cls-4,
.cls-5,
.cls-6,
.cls-8,
.cls-9 {
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.cls-2,
.cls-3,
.cls-4,
.cls-6 {
  stroke: #fff;
}

.cls-3 {
  fill: #fff;
}

.cls-4 {
  fill: #69953e;
}

.cls-5,
.cls-6,
.cls-8,
.cls-9 {
  fill: none;
}

.cls-7 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
}

.cls-8,
.cls-9 {
  stroke: #000;
}

.cls-9 {
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

#track {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.empty-space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="empty-space" id="emptySpace"></div>
<svg id="track" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="732.77" height="427.38" viewBox="0 0 732.77 427.38">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M547.06,142.5H183.58c-100.16,0-164.77,70.72-145.63,159s114.74,159,214.89,159H616.32c100.16,0,165.85-70.72,146.72-159S647.22,142.5,547.06,142.5Z" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M541.18,153.5H196.25c-95,0-156.75,65.81-139,147s108.07,147,203.11,147H605.28c95,0,157.79-65.81,140-147S636.22,153.5,541.18,153.5Z" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M532.12,167.5H211.86c-88.25,0-145.87,59.2-129.74,133s99.67,133,187.91,133H590.3c88.25,0,146.83-59.2,130.69-133S620.36,167.5,532.12,167.5Z" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M522,182.5H227.66c-81.11,0-134.31,52.92-119.87,119s91,119,172.1,119H574.26c81.11,0,135.19-52.92,120.74-119S603.13,182.5,522,182.5Z" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/>
    <path class="cls-3" d="M511.6,199.5H241.37c-74.46,0-124.13,45.2-111.55,102s82,102,156.48,102H556.52c74.46,0,124.94-45.2,112.36-102S586.06,199.5,511.6,199.5Z" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/>
    <path class="cls-4" d="M503.25,208.5H251.94c-69.25,0-115.52,41.59-104,93.5s76,93.5,145.29,93.5H544.56c69.25,0,116.27-41.59,104.73-93.5S572.5,208.5,503.25,208.5Z" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/>
    <line class="cls-5" x1="539.17" y1="366.25" x2="550.9" y2="426.88"/>
    <line class="cls-5" x1="519.69" y1="366.77" x2="531.32" y2="426.88"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="530.87" y1="373.39" x2="532.51" y2="381.88"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="531.24" y1="388.59" x2="532.88" y2="397.07"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="535.35" y1="388.59" x2="536.99" y2="397.07"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="532.61" y1="402.26" x2="534.25" y2="410.74"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="535.07" y1="414.91" x2="536.71" y2="423.39"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="537.31" y1="415.04" x2="541.28" y2="423.25"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="542.31" y1="415.14" x2="541.27" y2="423.28"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="536.01" y1="402.26" x2="537.65" y2="410.74"/>
    <line class="cls-6" x1="539.38" y1="402.3" x2="541.02" y2="410.78"/>
    <line class="cls-5" x1="552.76" y1="180.57" x2="592.89" y2="136.42"/>
    <path class="cls-5" d="M269.93,200c-2.05-31.81-13.24-58.54-25-59.78" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/>
    <line class="cls-5" x1="605.61" y1="345.21" x2="628.64" y2="358.42"/>
    <line class="cls-5" x1="643.77" y1="343.5" x2="667.51" y2="353.68"/>
    <line class="cls-5" x1="682.57" y1="328.67" x2="706.41" y2="335.8"/>
    <line class="cls-5" x1="712.3" y1="313.17" x2="731.66" y2="317.15"/>
    <path class="cls-9 path" d="M643.67,388.67c6.9-4,33.16-20.25,40.67-51.33,7.43-30.77-8.33-56.07-18.67-72.67-26.1-41.9-67.51-57.59-83.33-63.33a194.53,194.53,0,0,0-66-11.33c-129.09-1.54-180.12-3.33-276-.67a186.21,186.21,0,0,0-34,4c-15.77,3.33-34.94,7.39-52.67,20.67-7.61,5.7-29.05,23.66-35.33,52.67C107.89,314.9,147.8,354.8,157,364c26.42,26.41,56.79,34.85,75.33,40,21.76,6,37.54,6.58,81.33,7.33,60.89,1,91.34,1.57,107.33,1.33,38.41-.58,94.55-1.22,166.67-1.33" transform="translate(-34.09 -33.62)"/> <!-- i want to animate this path on scroll, and start it after the finish line, and end it at the finish line -->
</svg>
```

Comment: On your animated path if you comment the stroke dashoffset and dasharray the circle is not complete, I do not think that's intended and what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Hello @Jake , yes this is intended I don't want to have a full circle. I also tried to create a full circle for this path and the problem is here too, I'm not sure too understand where the problem is

Comment: try to change the path to 1300 instead of 1000  dashoffset and dasharray

Comment: @godfather Thank you so much this is almost working!! Do you have any explanations ?

Comment: go to inspect and select path cls-9 youll see  its the calculation

Comment: oh okay i understand now, thank you very much !

Comment: Your path length is 1302.38671875. Use this instead of 1000. To get the total length of a path in SVG use the `path.getTotalLength()` method. As an observation: you can use the `wheel` event instead. This way you don't have to care if the window is heigh enough.

Comment: @enxaneta you're right i didn't thought to use this method, thank you!